# Using NSE enquo with dply and tidyr (issue with complete(nesting(...), ...)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, rlang, tidyeval

I'm trying to use the NSE with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

I have a list of product, their volume per month per region. The products and regions have hierarchical structure (ProductLevel1 coarser than ProductLevel2 coarser than Product Level3 ...). Before making a graph, I want to add the months with no volume using `tidyr::nesting` and `tidyr::complete`.

This is at the level of `tidyr::nesting` the function seems to fail.

```
f_test <- function(IS1, finerProductLevel, finerRegionLevel) {  
  qfinerProductLevel <- enquo(finerProductLevel)
  qfinerRegionLevel <- enquo(finerRegionLevel)
  IS2 <- IS1 %>% 
    group_by(calDate, !! qfinerRegionLevel, !! qfinerProductLevel) %>%
    summarize(Vol = sum(Vol, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup()

  IS3 <- IS2 %>%
    complete(nesting(!! qfinerProductLevel, !! qfinerRegionLevel), 
             calDate, fill = list(Vol=0))
}
f_test(IS1, ProductLevel4, RegionLevel4_18)
```

the error I receive is:

```
Error in eval_tidy(xs[[i]], unique_output) : object 'ProductLevel4' not found
```

If I remove the `!!`s in the nesting function, then the error is

```
Error: Columns `qfinerProductLevel`, `qfinerRegionLevel` must be 1d atomic vectors or lists
```

There was a similar question in the past with no answer: [dplyr programming: unquote-splicing causes overscope error with complete() and nesting()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211743/dplyr-programming-unquote-splicing-causes-overscope-error-with-complete-and-n)

A sample of the dataset:

```
IS1 <- structure(list(COPASalesOffice = c("DACH", "DACH", "EMO", "EMO", 
"France", "French Africa", "Israel", "Italy", "Middle East", 
"Nordic", "South Hub", "South Hub", "Spain Portugal", "Spain Portugal", 
"Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "UK Ireland", "UK Ireland"), calDate = structure(c(16861, 
17440, 16983, 17410, 16436, 16709, 16161, 16222, 17136, 16526, 
16861, 16922, 16587, 17136, 16495, 16283, 16983, 16222, 16740
), class = "Date"), Vol = c(75.17, 121.731, 0, 23, 0, 15, 30, 
173.36, 0, 9.217, -1, 0, 0.849, 12.154, 0, 0, 25, 1, 20.313), 
    RegionLevel0 = c("EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", 
    "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", 
    "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR"
    ), RegionLevel1 = c("Europe", "Europe", "MEAR", "MEAR", "Europe", 
    "MEAR", "MEAR", "Europe", "MEAR", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
    "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
    "Europe"), RegionLevel2 = c("EU5-NB", "EU5-NB", "CIS", "CIS", 
    "EU5-NB", "MEA", "MEA", "EU5-NB", "MEA", "EU5-NB", "CEE", 
    "CEE", "EU5-NB", "EU5-NB", "CEE", "CEE", "CEE", "EU5-NB", 
    "EU5-NB"), RegionLevel4_18 = c("R01", "R01", "R20", "R20", 
    "R03", "R14", "R17", "R04", "R12", "R06", "R08", "R08", "R05", 
    "R05", "R09", "R09", "R09", "R02", "R02"), ProductLevel1 = c("aqueous", 
    "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", 
    "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", 
    "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous"
    ), ProductLevel2 = c("aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq4", 
    "aq4", "aq4", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", 
    "aq8", "aq4", "aq8", "aq8"), ProductLevel3 = c("8.24-44", 
    "8.24-44", "8.24-44", "8.24-44", "8.24-44", "4.24-44", "4.24-44", 
    "4.24-44", "8.A2", "8.24-44", "64in", "8.A2", "8.24-44", 
    "64in", "8.24-44", "8.24-44", "4.24-44", "8.24-44", "8.24-44"
    ), ProductLevel4 = c("T636-596-642, H&H", "T804, SC-P6/7/8/9000", 
    "T636-596-642, H&H", "T636-596-642, H&H", "T40X, 9000", "T692-693-694-698 Opr", 
    "T611-612, 74x0-94x0", "T611-612, 74x0-94x0", "T850, SCP800", 
    "T543-544, 40-76-9600", "T591, 11880", "T605-606, 48x0", 
    "T543-544, 40-76-9600", "T591, 11880", "T46X, 7000", "T602-603, 78x0-98x0", 
    "T692-693-694-698 Opr", "T47X, 9500", "T543-544, 40-76-9600"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("COPASalesOffice", "calDate", "Vol", "RegionLevel0", 
"RegionLevel1", "RegionLevel2", "RegionLevel4_18", "ProductLevel1", 
"ProductLevel2", "ProductLevel3", "ProductLevel4"))
```

and the SessionInfo:

```
Rstudio 1.1.442

R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base  

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.0   dplyr_0.7.4     purrr_0.2.4     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.8.0     tibble_1.4.2    ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.2.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the call to your `f_test()` function, the 2nd and 3rd arguments you are passing are names of objects that don't exist. You probably want to quote them so that they are passed as strings. Additionally, you probably want your `f_test()` function to return something... I suspect `return(IS3)` is the result you're expecting.

```
IS1 <- structure(list(COPASalesOffice = c("DACH", "DACH", "EMO", "EMO", "France", "French Africa", "Israel", "Italy", "Middle East", "Nordic", "South Hub", "South Hub", "Spain Portugal", "Spain Portugal", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "UK Ireland", "UK Ireland"), calDate = structure(c(16861, 17440, 16983, 17410, 16436, 16709, 16161, 16222, 17136, 16526, 16861, 16922, 16587, 17136, 16495, 16283, 16983, 16222, 16740 ), class = "Date"), Vol = c(75.17, 121.731, 0, 23, 0, 15, 30, 173.36, 0, 9.217, -1, 0, 0.849, 12.154, 0, 0, 25, 1, 20.313), RegionLevel0 = c("EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR", "EMEAR" ), RegionLevel1 = c("Europe", "Europe", "MEAR", "MEAR", "Europe", "MEAR", "MEAR", "Europe", "MEAR", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe"), RegionLevel2 = c("EU5-NB", "EU5-NB", "CIS", "CIS", "EU5-NB", "MEA", "MEA", "EU5-NB", "MEA", "EU5-NB", "CEE", "CEE", "EU5-NB", "EU5-NB", "CEE", "CEE", "CEE", "EU5-NB", "EU5-NB"), RegionLevel4_18 = c("R01", "R01", "R20", "R20", "R03", "R14", "R17", "R04", "R12", "R06", "R08", "R08", "R05", "R05", "R09", "R09", "R09", "R02", "R02"), ProductLevel1 = c("aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous", "aqueous" ), ProductLevel2 = c("aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq4", "aq4", "aq4", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq8", "aq4", "aq8", "aq8"), ProductLevel3 = c("8.24-44", "8.24-44", "8.24-44", "8.24-44", "8.24-44", "4.24-44", "4.24-44", "4.24-44", "8.A2", "8.24-44", "64in", "8.A2", "8.24-44", "64in", "8.24-44", "8.24-44", "4.24-44", "8.24-44", "8.24-44" ), ProductLevel4 = c("T636-596-642, H&H", "T804, SC-P6/7/8/9000", "T636-596-642, H&H", "T636-596-642, H&H", "T40X, 9000", "T692-693-694-698 Opr", "T611-612, 74x0-94x0", "T611-612, 74x0-94x0", "T850, SCP800", "T543-544, 40-76-9600", "T591, 11880", "T605-606, 48x0", "T543-544, 40-76-9600", "T591, 11880", "T46X, 7000", "T602-603, 78x0-98x0", "T692-693-694-698 Opr", "T47X, 9500", "T543-544, 40-76-9600" )), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ), .Names = c("COPASalesOffice", "calDate", "Vol", "RegionLevel0", "RegionLevel1", "RegionLevel2", "RegionLevel4_18", "ProductLevel1", "ProductLevel2", "ProductLevel3", "ProductLevel4"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

f_test <- function(IS1, finerProductLevel, finerRegionLevel) {  
  qfinerProductLevel <- enquo(finerProductLevel)
  qfinerRegionLevel <- enquo(finerRegionLevel)
  IS2 <- IS1 %>% 
    group_by(calDate, !! qfinerRegionLevel, !! qfinerProductLevel) %>%
    summarize(Vol = sum(Vol, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup()

  IS3 <- IS2 %>%
    complete(nesting(!! qfinerProductLevel, !! qfinerRegionLevel), 
             calDate, fill = list(Vol=0))

  return(IS3)
}
f_test(IS1, "ProductLevel4", "RegionLevel4_18")
```

---

**Update based on comment**

If you're trying to replicate the result of something like this...

```
IS1 %>% 
  group_by(calDate, ProductLevel4, RegionLevel4_18) %>%
  summarize(Vol = sum(Vol, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(nesting(ProductLevel4, RegionLevel4_18), 
           calDate, fill = list(Vol=0))
```

with a function that excepts "bare variable names" (not strings), like this...

```
f_test(IS1, ProductLevel4, RegionLevel4_18)
```

then you could write it like this...

```
f_test <-
  function(df, grp1, grp2) {
    sym_grp1 <- rlang::ensym(grp1)
    sym_grp2 <- rlang::ensym(grp2)
    df %>% 
      group_by(calDate, !!sym_grp1, !!sym_grp2) %>% 
      summarize(Vol = sum(Vol, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      complete(nesting(!!sym_grp1, !!sym_grp2), 
               calDate, fill = list(Vol=0))
  }

f_test(IS1, ProductLevel4, RegionLevel4_18)
```

---

**Further Update**

You could also use `rlang::ensyms()` to do both/all variable at once, and then `!!!` to unquote and splice them...

```
test <- function(data, var1, var2) {
  vars <- rlang::ensyms(var1, var2)

  data %>%
    group_by(calDate, !!!vars) %>%
    summarize(Vol = sum(Vol, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    complete(nesting(!!!vars), calDate, fill = list(Vol=0))
}
test(IS1, ProductLevel4, RegionLevel4_18)
```

which would then allow you to use `...` to accept an arbitrary number of arguments...

```
test <- function(data, ...) {
  vars <- rlang::ensyms(...)

  data %>%
    group_by(calDate, !!!vars) %>%
    summarize(Vol = sum(Vol, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    complete(nesting(!!!vars), calDate, fill = list(Vol=0))
}
test(IS1, ProductLevel4, RegionLevel4_18)
test(IS1, ProductLevel4)
test(IS1, ProductLevel4, RegionLevel4_18, ProductLevel2)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. When replacing enquo by rlang::sym, it works. Then it is solved, even if I hoped for a solution with enquo. When I reproduce your proposition with enquo, the columns are named \`"ProductLevel4"\` and \`"RegionLevel4_18"\` and their values are replaced by a unique value is "ProductLevel4" and "RegionLevel4_18".

Comment: I think the confusion might be related to `dplyr` not yet being fully converted over to the new `rlang` style of things, while `tidyr` has been already (why `enquo` works with `group_by` but not `nesting`).